# Scipy maximizing linear programming doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-programming

I have the following:

```
ball = scipy.optimize.linprog(array([0,0,1]), A, b)
```

where

```
A = 
array([[-1.0,  0.0,  1.0],
   [ 1.0,  0.0,  1.0],
   [ 0.0, -1.0,  1.0],
   [ 0.0,  1.0,  1.0]], dtype=float128)

b = array([ 0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0], dtype=float128)
```

We can maximize this by hand to get the answer `x = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]`. Yet scipy gives me

```
  status: 0
   slack: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.])
 success: True
     fun: -0.0
       x: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 0
```

Which is simply the wrong answer! Is my code wrong, or did I find a bug?

EDIT:
To verify that the solution given by scipy is not optimal, do

```
np.all(np.dot(A, np.array([0.5,0.5,0.5])) <= b)
```

to see that my solution satisfies the constraints. Then note that

```
np.dot(np.array([0,0,1]), np.array([0.5,0.5,0.5])) > np.dot(np.array([0,0,1]), np.array([0,0,0]))
```

to see it is at least a better solution. In fact, it is the optimal solution.

EDIT 2:
`scipy.__version__ = 0.16.0`

Comment: If I try to run it, I get an error: `Invalid input for linprog with method = 'simplex'.  Number of columns in A_ub must be equal to the size of c`. Py3.4, scipy 0.15.1

Comment: Sorry, forgot a `-1`. It will work now. The above is a MWE from my more complicated code, hence the error.

Comment: According to the docs, `linprog` finds the minimum, while in the last part of your question you admit yourself that your solution results in a larger value.

Comment: OOOH I'm so dumb!!! Classic case of RTFM. When I was working out the math I was maximizing, didn't bother to check what scipy does. Sorry!!! Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, [`linprog`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) finds the minimum, while your proposed solution is the maximum.

Comment: Sure enough, replace the first parameter with its negative, and the minimization becomes maximization, matching the OP's answer.